# How to: Script Out Unique Constraint creation script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, unique-constraint

I have a list of Unique Constraints which creation scripts I would need.

Is there an easy way to do this? (something like querying sp_help, sys.objects,..)
Or would I need to do this manually for every constraint ( on 30+ tables)?

Workaround I am using at the moment:
in SSMS

- Object Explorer

  - Database
  - Table
  - Constraints

    - 'script constraint as'
    - 'CREATE to'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnName = c.name,
    TableName = t.name,   
    CreateCmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) + '.' + t.name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + i.name + ' UNIQUE(' + c.name + ')'
FROM 
     sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON i.index_id = ic.index_id AND i.object_id = ic.object_id
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns c ON ic.column_id = c.column_id AND ic.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE 
     is_unique_constraint = 1
```

This gives you a listing of columns and tables where a unique constraint is applied to, and it gives you the T-SQL command to newly create that `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`

Answer (score 2):

Ever used Powershell?

```
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo");

$svr = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("YourServerInstance");

$svr.Databases["YourDatabase"].Tables[0].Indexes[0].Script();
```

`Databases`, `Tables` and `Indexes` are collections you can iterate over.

Comment: FYI, the library that the asker's current manual approach is using is the same as this answer does.  Interestingly the sys.objects view lists all the objects within a database and some of the objects it lists are not readily available in the object model that I have been able to discern.